# Referencing a JSON schema from the current directory

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

Given a file `appsettings.json` and a JSON schema file `appsettings.schema.json` which both reside in the same folder, how can you use the `$schema` property to point to the schema file so that it loads without error?

eg.

appsettings.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "appsettings.schema.json",
  ...
}
```

appsettings.schema.json

```js
{
  ...
}
```

With the above path, I get an error in Visual Studio Code:

```
Unable to load schema from '\appsettings.schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\appsettings.schema.json'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was sure I'd tried this before, but `"./appsettings.schema.json"` works